# how to self-reference a class in Python?

Tags: python

I want this Template class to accept children of itself and other types with `type(i) in self._allowed_types`.

```
class Template():
    _allowed_types = [str, Template, SafeHtml]
```

Above code throws this:

```
NameError: name 'Template' is not defined
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add the class after the class is defined:

```
class Template():
    _allowed_types = [str, SafeHtml]

Template._allowed_types.append(Template)
```

The class body, by necessity, is run before the class object can be created, so the name `Template` is not defined *yet*. But you can always alter class attributes after the object has been created.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is using properties to be lazy about the field.

```
class Test(object):
    @property
    def allowed(self):
        return [str, Test]

t = Test()
print Test in t.allowed
```

Comment: I don't see why the downvote as well - this is certainly a good way to do it - and only in few cases should not be preferred

Comment: I didn't downvote. Just commenting 7 years later that this doesn't work if the desired usage is `Test.allowed` because that returns a `property` object, not `[str, Test]`. Perhaps that's what @jsbueno meant as one of the "few cases" where this is not preferred?

Answer (score 0):

Another (and, perhaps, a cleaner) way is to declare an intermediate class:

```
class BasicTemplate():
    pass

class Template(BasicTemplate):
    _allowed_types = [str, BasicTemplate]
```

`BasicTemplate` can be completely dummy, or have some useful code in it. Having a template that is *not* allowed to include itself might come in handy at some point.

Of course, this would require `isinstance` instead of `type()` to check types, but that's a good idea anyways.

Comment: Nice maybe for presenting "another way", but IMHO  not "cleaner" - this dirties the class hierarchy, forcing one where there was none - and if there was already one in place, maybe worsen things by creating the need for intermediate classes, or a second hierarchy with multiple inheritance: as you can see, it gets ugly pretty fast.

It is much simpler to simply allow an string with the class name, and check for strings and name retrieval from the relevant modules - like Django does.

Comment: @jsbueno: yes, this is subjective, and quite pointless to talk about without seeing the whole picture. In my book, out-of-class fiddling with private members is a big no-no, the same for stringed identifiers.